# Why is "give under the the weight" grammatically correct here?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Why is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> We were afraid that the rickety bed would give under the the weight of ten people.

I think that it should be '.....give up under the weight.....'

Comment: According to dictionaries, "to give" can mean "to bend".  "the rickety bed would give(bend) under the weight of ten people" is correct.

Comment: When structures collapse, whether under excessive weight or for other reasons, they are said **to give way**. The bridge gave way under the weight of the train.** (To give way: (of a support or structure) be unable to carry a load or withstand a force; collapse or break.)

Answer (score 3):

As dan said:

"To give up" is a phrasal verb, and it could be correct in this sentence. This would be anthropomorphizing (attributing human emotions to) **the rickety bed**, and it would have the connotation of *breaking completely*.

But! "To give" is also a perfectly acceptable verb. It can mean "to break" or "to collapse," but it can also carry the less-catastrophic meaning "to flex/bend." (Though in the context of the sentence the more destructive meaning is probably intended.)